# VBA Check For Missing Data for Dymanic Range

Tags: excel, dynamic-data, missing-data, before-save, vba

I am stuck on figuring out how to make a dynamic range for this database page for a project to check if the Phase data is missing before saving the workbook.  The database page will continue to grow and not sure how to make this range dynamic.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rsave As Range
Dim cell As Range

Sheets("Database").Select

Set rsave = Range("a7:a125")

For Each cell In rsave
If cell = "" Then
    Dim missdata
    missdata = MsgBox("Missing Phase Data", vbOKOnly, "Missing Phase Data")
    Cancel = True
    cell.Select
    Exit For
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: depends on how it is going to be called and/or used by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the full story on missing items:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As String, N As Long, cl As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A7:A" & N)
    For Each cl In r
        If cl.Value = "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & cl.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next cl
    If msg = "" Then Exit Sub
        MsgBox msg
        Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Both of these work great - thanks.  The only problem I noticed is if there is data missing in that column in the last row, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I am fairly new to VBA in Excel, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I have added a **+1** to the line that calculates **N**

Comment: That's it?  I thought it would be more complicated.  Thanks for your help!